# How to call multiple http service in parallel from angular component

Tags: angular

How can I call my methods from component only after multiple service call is completed?

I have a service.ts file which has one method that will return the array with different values based on the key (i.e. obj here) as shown below:-

```
getdata(type:numer)
 {
   // make a post call to get the data
 }
```

Here, in component.ts file, I have two methods which will call the above service method as shown below:- 
These 2 methods are used to fill the dropdown in html when clicked on edit form button

```
method1()
{
   this.service.getdata().subscribe((res: any) => {
      data1 = res;
    });
}

method2()
{
   this.service.getdata().subscribe((res: any) => {
      data2 = res;
    });
}
```

I have one more method which will fill the form data on edit click

```
fillForm()
{
    // do something
}
```

Now, my requirement is I need to call method1 and method2 in component.ts
and also I need to call this fillForm method only after above two methods are completed 
as I need to make sure the dropdown should be filled before editing the form

Comment: Have you tried adding callback() functions so that when a method completes the callback() is called and you know that method1 has finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello if you are using **rxjs 5** you can use Observable zipping :

```js
Observable.zip(
    this.method1(),
    this.method2()
).subscribe(
    ([dataFromMethod1, dataFromMethod2]) => {
        // do things
    },
    (error) => console.error(error),
    () => {
        // do things when all subscribes are finished
        this.fillform();
    }
)
```

With **rxjs 6**, simply change `Observable.zip` by `forkJoin` :

```js
forkJoin(
    this.method1(),
    this.method2()
).subscribe(
    ([dataFromMethod1, dataFromMethod2]) => {
        // do things
    },
    (error) => console.error(error),
    () => {
        // do things when all subscribes are finished
        this.fillform();
    }
)
```

You will need to change your methods to return Observables :

```js
method1()
{
   return this.service.getdata();
}

method2()
{
   return this.service.getdata();
}
```

Comment: `zip` is not parallel, it's like a zipper on a jacket, one after the other until completed, `combineLatest`, `merge` and `forkJoin` are acceptable alternatives.

Comment: In rxjs 5, using `Observable.zip` make parallel calls. However, I agree with your comment for rxjs6, that's why I used `forkJoin`

Comment: Note that `this.fillform()` will not be executed when any of the Observables throws an error. Source: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html. For things you need to do whether there are errors or not, you should use [`.finally()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html)